# Why can't I change the background color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.configure(background=blue)
mainloop()
```

Comment: i messed something up. I accidentally put "master = Tk()" on the same line as "master.configure(background=blue)

Comment: When I fixed the obvious problem with `blue`, your code works as expected. The window background turns blue.

Comment: @BryanOakley Maybe the problem is not that obvious to the OP? OP, why can't you change the background colour? Any error messages?

Comment: Guys, thank you for the help. My son asked this question, he's 11. He's completely new to programming. Thank you guys for the help. I don't know if he's seen the answers yet. He didn't ask me for help or I would have pointed out the obvious that he just needed to add quotes to the color since it is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo problem, also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358929/i-was-trying-to-change-the-color-of-the-background-but-i-cant#comment83709850_48358929). In the above code snippet, `blue` is a reference to an object that has never been initiated. OP must have meant `'blue'` or something similar. See fixed code below:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.configure(background='blue')
mainloop()
```

Worth mentioning that there is already a built-in `exit` method which above code conflicts with.

---

Also, in my humble opinion, more readable version of the above code:

```
import tkinter as tk


master = tk.Tk()
master['background'] = 'blue'
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Please see my comment above.